# Why is alarm being called but not ringing?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, ringtone

This is me calling the alarmmanager,

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

and this is my receiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    Toast.makeText(arg0, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(arg0, uri);
    ringtone.play();
    if (ringtone.isPlaying()) {
        Log.e("Yep","Its playin");
    }else {
        Log.e("NOp","just nop");
    }
```

when the receiver is called, i always get Yep,Its playing but the ringtone never rings... its not the volume i am sure of it, so what else could be the problem? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using MediaPlayer instead:

```
Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager. TYPE_ALARM);
try{
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(arg0, uri);
    mp.start();
} catch(Exception e){}
```

Also try using `RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION` instead of `RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM`

Are you working on the emulator? Because it does not have a ringtone by default.
If you are, you can use your code as it is (because it should work on actual device, but can fail if no ringtone is et e.g. silent mode.) by doing the following:

Upload a MP3 file in your /sdcard folder using DDMS, restart the emulator, then open the Media application, browse to your MP3 file, long press on it and select "Use as phone ringtone".

Comment: Yes i am using the emulator, so i tried the media player and it still didn't work.. i realised that im getting this msg E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set..does it mean anything? @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa

Comment: I updated my answer to fix that. That happened because I did not set any controller to the MediaPlayer. MediaPlayers need MediaControllers for controlling music playback, but only if you need them. You may choose not to use them if you don't

Comment: i tried that too and still not working...that try catch did absolutely nothing...still got the controller msg and no sound...thank you for the help anyway @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa

Comment: im also getting E/AudioSink: received unknown event type: 1 inside CallbackWrapper !
this every second in my error log

Comment: now i tried it with a mp3 file    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(arg0, R.raw.ring);
        mp.start();   and still no luck.... can anyone help ?